# How to change ionic datetime picker to localtime?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I just want to show my localtime when presented the datetime picker. I've tried a few different formats but none worked.

```
<ion-col size="4">
          <ion-item>
            <ion-datetime placeholder="Start" display-format="H:mm" picker-Format="DD MMM YYYY H:mm" [(ngModel)]="shift.start1">
            </ion-datetime>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-col>
```

Comment: Get the date value into class and set like const date_value = new Date(here u put the binded value of the picker).toLocalTime() or localtimestring, something like that, check it with auto complete or google it , its a javascript method.